# C++ window (winapi, not console), closes instantly

Tags: c++, windows

I just can't see what's wrong with this code.. it seems to be the same as the MS tutorial code..  can somebody take a quick look at it for me?

http://pastebin.com/hiFAR0gg

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is wrong with it? Is it not compiling, crashing on start up, something else? Also, I would recommend copying the code into the post, in case that link dies the question still makes sense.

Comment: I didn't put the code in the post because it's pretty long..  the problem with the program is that as soon as the window opens, it closes.  It appears normally, but it closes instantly.

Comment: The site will add scroll bars to your code and format it nicely if you paste it correctly. 96 lines isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning S_OK (#defined as `((HRESULT)0L)`) from your InitWindow function. When checking the return value, you are checking if it is TRUE (non-zero): `if (!InitWindow(...))`. 0 will be interpreted as false, so it is failing this test.

If I change the call to InitWindow to:

```
if (InitWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow) != S_OK)
   return FALSE;
```

It works fine

Comment: I changed it to `if (FAILED(InitWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)))`